# How to remove this bathtub diverter spigot?

Tags: bathroom, faucet, bathroom-fixtures

I'm trying to remove a bathtub diverter spigot, but I can't tell whether it is a screw-on or a slip-on (with a hex bolt at the bottom).  My spigot has the notch where a hex bolt would normally be, but when I look inside the notch, I can't see anything but a metal plate, a plastic tab, and some white silicone.  Does this mean that I have a screw-on or do I have to remove something to get to the hex bolt inside the notch?  I can turn the spigot some with my hand, but I think the silicone is resisting the torque.  I don't want to just start wrenching away without some better information.

Any idea on how to remove this type of spigot?  Thanks!

[image: faucet]

Comment: Is there a cap screw in the outlet end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to slide the white plastic tab towards the mouth of the spigot.  its essentially like a quick fit pneumatic fitting.  its a spring loaded compression fitting.  sliding the plastic tab forward against the spring pressure releases the seal and lets you slide the spigot off of the wallpipe.  you can twist a little to make it easier and lubricate with dishsoap to get it to move.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I'm going to give it a try and report back.